# Issue with creating multiple JComponents with a for loop

Tags: java, swing

I am running a few lines of code to create a variable number of JLabels, each one in its own row. This is working fine, until I get to the last JLabel of the for loop. This one always gets stuck on the left edge of the JFrame.

Here's my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MultipleLabelsTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<JLabel> labels;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MultipleLabelsTest window = new MultipleLabelsTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MultipleLabelsTest() {
        initialize();
        labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        createXTextBoxes(2);
    }

    private void createXTextBoxes(int i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Number " + (j + 1));
            label.setBounds(30, (18 + 20*j), 200, 16);
            System.out.println(label.getBounds());
            frame.getContentPane().add(label);
            labels.add(label);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Here's a screenshot of the result: http://imgur.com/8GZkrl1
And of the console output: http://imgur.com/n6U3brN

Any idea why it behaves this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try a layout manager? [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a good visual guide to the layout managers of Swing.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify